# New comment notification should be skipped if I'm known to have seen it

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

Someone commented on an answer I've written, and I noticed there was a "1 more comment" message. I clicked on it, and saw the comment. I even replied.

A couple of minutes later I'm seeing a red [1] over my "inbox", and the comment is what I'm notified about.

Comments with which I've known to have interacted - e.g. by clicking "more comments" or by replying below them - should be considered as not requiring notification.